# Refused UK visa for the second time due to lack of ties. What are my options?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, algerian-citizens

I'm a 19-year-old male Algerian citizen born in England.

I applied for a child visitor visa in 2014. I was 17 at that time I was going to visit my brother (EEA) citizen in London. I got a refusal because I didn't provide documents such as my brother's passport copy, then after nearly 2 years I applied this year for a visit visa on July 25 with both my parents to travel on August 28. I included all the necessary documents including a school certificate for the academic school year 2015/2016, we received responses on August 11. My parents both got their visas but mine was refused and the reason was:

> You have stated that you wish to visit the United Kingdom for a period of ten days. As evidence of you personal circumstances in Algeria, you have provided a translation of an educational certificate, stating that you are enrolled for the 2015/16 academic year, which I note to now be drawing to a close. I'm not satisfied that the documents provided demonstrate any significant ties that you may have your country of residence, such as may encourage or guarantee your departure from the United Kingdom at the conclusion of your proposed visit.
>
> Due to these reasons, I'm not satisfied with your intentions in wishing to travel to the United Kingdom at this time, nor that intend to leave the United Kingdom at the conclusion of your proposed visit. In addition, I'm not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the visitors routes.
> In relation to this decision there is no right of appeal or right to an administrative review.

I was heartbroken when I received this response, I cried a lot because I want so much to go the UK to see my place of birth. I find it so unfair. I mean I applied during the summer break so I couldn't provide my 2016/17 school certificate and as it's the summer vacation! What else to do than to travel! And I can neither appeal nor seek a review. My questions are:

- Who do I complain to? My father suggested to write a letter explaining everything to the British embassy in Algiers.
- I’m thinking to apply during November to go during the winter break and will provide a 2016/17 school certificate and explain everything on the application form that I have a baccalaureate (A level equivalent) and that I will have to come back but I’m afraid to get a refusal and they might think I'm crazy about going to the UK and that I will go and not return.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly are you asking us. Who do you complain to? Nobody; visa issuance is a privilege, not a right. Or do you mean how can you appeal this decision?

Comment: With respect to visitor visa applications there is no right of appeal or right to administrative review. The only person you can complain to is the person who prepared your visa application.

Answer (score 11):

You applied for a Standard Visitor Visa and were refused. Normally we need to see a scan of the refusal notice because the person contemplates fixing the problems but first needs help interpreting the refusal grounds.

You are asking about how to make a complaint.

> Who do I Complain to ?

You can always complain to their  [executive offices on Marsham Street](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/home-office). I have done this before and and can attest that they will not entertain complaints dealing with individual cases; instead the complaint needs to raise a global concern like when the biometric servers crashed for more than a week. In your case you will get back a boiler-plate letter explaining that you need to make a fresh application. But certainly nothing prevents your drafting and sending a complaint directly to them...

```
The Home Secretary
Policy Unit
2 Marsham Street
London, United Kingdom
SW1P 4DF
```

Secondarily, [UKVI operates a subsidiary complaints procedure](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration/about/complaints-procedure) within the Home Office and they take incoming complaints very seriously. Their policy is to segregate the complaints streams from the operational streams (that's a good thing) so as to prevent conflicts of interest and corruption. There's a guidance page [here](https://eforms.homeoffice.gov.uk/outreach/_static/ukvi-international-complaints.html).  You will get back a boiler-plate letter explaining that you need to make a fresh application.

Your next question...

> My father suggested to write a letter explaining everything to the British embassy in Algiers

This will also work; there is a [British Consulate General](https://www.gov.uk/government/world/organisations/british-embassy-algiers) in Algiers. They will log it and then segregate it from the operational stream for further handling. You will then get back a boiler-plate letter explaining that you need to make a fresh application.

As a side note, applications submitted in Algiers are actually sent to  [Lunar House in Croydon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_House) for decision-making! It's part of their hub and spoke programme, but Croydon does not engage the public for Standard Visitor Visas.

Those are your avenues for a complaint.

For your implicit question...

> I cried a lot because I want so much to go the Uk to see my place of birth I find it so unfair

Adverse decisions are very disappointing. There's an article here on the site with a section called "**I am desperate...**" and another one titled "**I cannot provide a compelling case**" which you may find helpful. It's at [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

> i'm afraid to get a refusal and they might thing I'm crazy about going to the Uk and that I will go and not return

Yes, that's right. Northern Africa has a fairly high risk profile and you will need very stable circumstances in order to be successful the next time.

If you want more substantive help next time(s), you will need to include scans of your refusal notices **in a new question**.

---

TSE colleague [Michael Hampton](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3221/michael-hampton) (to whom thanks) pointed out [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76601/i-got-a-refusal-for-the-second-time/76609#comment168144_76601) that there is no path of appeal or administrative review for visitor refusals. This is stated explicitly at the bottom of all refusal notices.

Also: for others following this thread, the Chief included Algiers in his 2011 inspection. There were some hits, but overall the inspection cleared up a lot of doubts about UKBI's operation in Africa. The report is [here](http://icinspector.independent.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/EMBARGOED-A-comparative-inspection-of-the-UK-Border-Agency-visa-sections-in-Africa.pdf). (I am in the people who admire the Chief's work and see him as one of the "good guys".

Comment: The lack of documents for the following academic year concerned me. It should have been possible to show _something_ to indicate plans to continue attending university.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, indeed, but we would need to see the scan in order to learn what the ECO actually wrote. The OP's text version left out the refusal grounds for example. The circumstances paragraph(s) are also missing. See the META thread :)